# Array is parsing as string in auto-complete control

Tags: jquery, arrays, string, easyautocomplete

I am using [EasyAutoComplete](http://easyautocomplete.com/guide#sec-templates) to provide auto-complete control on my page.

I am passing it an array as a variable. The variable is an array that I can step through with index and looks good to me. But when passed to this plugin, the input control only has one selection, which looks like this...

name1,name2,name3

It should look like this...

name1
name2
name3

as individual selections. Here is my code...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var dispatchNames = [];

$('.square').each(function () {

    //convert each div with .square class toString
    var square = $(this).html().toString();

    //grab availability value (if True, tech is available)
    var availability = $(this).find('tr:eq(4)').find('td').text();

    //grab IP (if exists, tech is online)
    online = $(this).find('tr:eq(3)').find('td').text()        

    if ((availability === "True") && (online.indexOf("10.") === 0)) {

        //grab tech name
        dispatchNames.push([$(this).find('tr:eq(0)').find('td').text()]);

    }

})

var availableTechs = {
  data: [dispatchNames],
};

$("#dispatchTechs").easyAutocomplete(availableTechs);

  //alert(dispatchNames);

})
```

I can step through 'dispatchNames' as an array, but when I pass it to 'availableTechs', it is one long string.

I have tried splitting the string, etc, and it is always the same result.

Please advise if there is something I need to do for 'dispatchNames' before passing.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

easyAutocomplete plugin works like this...

```
var options = {
  data: ["blue", "green", "pink", "red", "yellow"]
};

$("#basics").easyAutocomplete(options);
```

Instead of providing an array for data:, I am trying to pass it an array in a variable, which apparently is being treated as a single object. That, I believe, is what I seek assistance with.

**UPDATE**

Using Match...

```
        var availableTechs = {

    data: dispatchNames,
    list: {
        match: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
```

};

```
$("#dispatchTech").easyAutocomplete(availableTechs);
```

})

Here is the console error when using match:

```
7jquery.easy-autocomplete.js:64 Uncaught TypeError: element.search is not a function
    at Object.method (jquery.easy-autocomplete.js:64)
    at match (jquery.easy-autocomplete.js:653)
    at findMatch (jquery.easy-autocomplete.js:630)
    at proccessData (jquery.easy-autocomplete.js:613)
    at ListBuilderService.processData (jquery.easy-autocomplete.js:455)
    at loadData (jquery.easy-autocomplete.js:1338)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (jquery.easy-autocomplete.js:1308)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.js:5183)
    at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.3.1.js:4991)
```

Comment: try `$("#dispatchTechs").easyAutocomplete(availableTechs.data.join(" "))`. This will create a string from an array joining with a space e.g. name1 name2 name3

Comment: Hi there. I think I want the opposite? I do not want to create a string. I need a list of items, not a string. Thank you!

Comment: I see where the confusion was, and have fixed my post. The desired output is a standard choice-list. Basically the array that I pass to the input control should be a list of items to choose from. Instead, it is all of the items in the array as one string, so there is only one selection in the list. I hope that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Oh I see what it is you need. Just pass `var availableTechs = { data: dispatchNames, };`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! That is it! Can you explain what happened there? It looks like instead of passing `dispatchNames` as an array after `data:`, you passed `data: dispatchNames,` ...which separates the declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an array wrapped within an array, in `availableTechs.data`.

Your array at the moment looks like:

```
[0]=>
  [
   0=>'name1', 
   1=>'name2', 
   2=>'name3'
  ]
```

What you need to do is remove that array wrapper.

```
var availableTechs = {
  data: dispatchNames,
};
```

And now your output is:

```
[
  0=>'name1', 
  1=>'name2', 
  2=>'name3'
]
```

Comment: This is the answer. I had found the issue but you explained to me what to do about it, thank you very much!

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I have one more issue. The Match documentation for EasyAutocomplete http://easyautocomplete.com/guide#sec-match looks simple enough. I add the match method and the autocomplete just stops working. No errors, no syntax problems, but it no longer displays any list in the input control. I have edited the question above to show the additional code. Is this something I am doing wrong?